# What mirror download does UK need?

Tags: mirror

I am currently looking to download Blender to make 3d objects for use in the Unity 5 Game Engine, but when having a look at what version to download, there is no version for the UK. Also, is there any difference between the .msi and .zip, or is it just that one is manual and one is automatic? 
Thank you.

Comment: I dont think there is any difference, both for mirror locations or install packages

Comment: even the download speed difference is negligible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you choose Germany or Netherlands as both are right next to each other but US is far further away if you live in the UK. As far as I know there is no major difference in speed when using the Netherland mirror 1 or 2. MSI is the installer and the zip has the actual program in it thus using the zip will mean that the Blender won't show up in your program files.